# loading animation using jquery to display inside a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am displaying a loading icon using jQuery whenever an ajax call takes place as below:

```js
$body = $("body");
$(document).on({
  ajaxStart: function() { $body.addClass("loading");    },
  ajaxStop: function() { $body.removeClass("loading"); }    
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display:    none;
  position:   fixed;
  z-index:    1000;
  top:        0;
  left:       0;
  height:     100%;
  width:      100%;
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
    url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif') 
    50% 50% 
    no-repeat;
}
body.loading {
  overflow: hidden;   
}
body.loading .modal {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal"><!-- Place at bottom of page --></div>
```

This is loading fine whenever an ajax takes place, but its obvious the loading icon would be displaying in the body hiding the UI at the back. Instead of that I want to display the loading only inside that particular div. In the attached html file i want to make the loading display only inside the

```
"div id= box1"
```

[**Link to HTML File**](http://pastebin.com/tr1sSDm2)

Comment: have you tried like: `$("#box1").addClass("loading");` and `$("#box1").removeClass("loading");` instead of `$body`?

Comment: Yes i tried this nothing happens.$(document).on({
                ajaxStart: function() { $("#box1").addClass("loading");    },
                ajaxStop: function() { $("#box1").removeClass("loading"); }    
            });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by vijayP is the right direction.

The CSS has to be modified since you have limited the loading class to only the body element.

```
.loading {
   overflow: hidden;   
}
.loading .modal {
   display: block;
}
```

Then in the JavaScript:

```
$(document).on({
  ajaxStart: function() { $("#box1").addClass("loading");    },
  ajaxStop:  function() { $("#box1").removeClass("loading"); }    
});
```

Comment: I even edited the css as per your suggestion and tried but no luck.

Comment: @HarnishKumar I checked it on my system and now I see the problem. Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308708/making-only-portion-of-screen-modal-with-jquery-ui

Comment: So should i wana try adding z-index in css and see?

Comment: Yes, try it. Also if you're open to using a library, you can try the jQuery BlockUI plugin. It allows blocking only a certain part of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code a bit and i hope that will get you going for now.

```js
$body = $("body");
$(document).on({
  ajaxStart: function() { $body.addClass("loading");    },
  ajaxStop: function() { $body.removeClass("loading"); }    
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display:    none;
  position:   fixed;
  z-index:    1000;
  top:        0;
  left:       0;
  height:     100%;
  width:      100%;
  /*background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
    url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif') 
    50% 50% 
    no-repeat;*/
}
body.loading {
  overflow: hidden;   
}
body.loading .modal {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif" />
<!-- Place at bottom of page --></div>
```

Comment: The loading is displaying even before the ajax call and is not stopping after the ajax request.