# How to load dynamic data in sync with static data when loading an HTML file?

Tags: html, angularjs, dynamic

When I am loading a web page which consists of static and dynamic text(using AngularJS). That static data is loading first and then dynamic after few seconds. Because of which I can clearly see a change in alignment of the line.

**Code Sample:**

> Valid for
>   {{$root.configParameters.TWDCQUOTEVALIDITY}} days.

**Original Text:** Valid for 30 days. **(30 is dynamic)**

**1st sec:** Valid for days.

**2nd sec:** Valid for 30 days.

Please suggest what should be the possible solution for this.

Comment: I think this is something that would have to come from server side with the page unless you can start loading the js code as the rest of the page is loading.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do for that because the data is loading dynamically it is purely based on your connection and server but as an alternative you can place a loader until the whole text is loaded 
 Like rather than displaying the whole text you can just display loading and once if the complete data renders into html then you can display the whole text 
 If you feel this is also no proper then just add a css `display:none` for the whole text and in jquery write a function to remove that css after the complete text loaded then you can get
 [This will help you with the situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39032139/loading-animation-using-jquery-to-display-inside-a-particular-div) 
 
 **1st Sec: nothing will be displayed** 
  **2nd Sec: Valid for 30 Days** 
 this is the best way i think